# Postgres execute requests isolatedly

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.6, pgadmin-4, application-design

Users submit schema and query. I need to execute them and return the result.
But if multiple requests have the same table in the schema mentioned, then I am getting conflicts (which is as expected). I can delete this schema/data immediately after execution. No need to store further. Still unable to achieve for concurrent requests.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You have to be more specific. What do these requests look like? Why is there a conflict? Why do you want to delete your database data after each request? Why are you working with outdated software?

Comment: I am working on online sql compiler kind of usecase where users sends schema and query to execute and send result as response. As per the use case no need to save this schema or queries after returning a response. 
If multiple users send the below request concurrently, conflict occurs due to table name (hope you got scenario by now for conflict)

Schema:
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT
);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (2);

query:
SELECT * FROM test;

Comment: Well, give everybody a different database.

Comment: You might want to read about [schemata](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createschema.html) (not in the sense in which you've used the term).